# Email Contacts Calendar software with Google Sync

Tags: email, evolution, contacts

I'm searching for an application that can do this. Currently I'm using Evolution but I don't really like it.

Comment: Thunderbird with some addons can handle that. Consider Lightning (for general Calender), Provider for Google Calender (for Google Cal Sync) and gContactSync (for google contacts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu is shipped with **Thunderbird** as the default email program.  It had contacts (called **Address Book**) by default.  You can click on the **Add-ons** option to add your preferred Calendar.  Using `calendar` in the add-ons search field you'll find a number of calendars.  I believe the most popular one is **Lighting**.  While some of the others might also, Lightning functions seamlessly with the Google contacts (**Provider for Google Calendar**).

**gContactSync** will sync your address book with Google.

The Google sync components are for syncing with your mobile devices.

Thunderbird is a Mozilla application.  While it has many features and pluggins available.  It's a very lightweight application.